# How can I remove a broken favorites list item from Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I added a folder from one of our servers to the favorites list on Finder and I don't know whether I moved the directory or whether the favorites list just doesn't play nice with folders accessed via server, but the item doesn't work on the favorites bar anymore (click seems to just refresh the server's root directory) and additionally I can't right click to remove the item like other non-broken items on the list.

How can I remove a broken favorites list item from Finder?

Comment: You can't drag it out, wait a bit until that cloud appears, then remove it? What happens when you right-click? Nothing?

Comment: @slhck nope the cloud doesn't appear, dragging it to the trash does nothing, and right click does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off your networking (turn off wi-fi, unplug ethernet), re-login or restart, and then see if it will drag out. Drag a few inches, and hold 5-10 seconds for the cloud to appear. Years ago, I would have trouble with server folder aliases somewhat like this (pre-sidebar of course). Its possible something is hung up trying to resolve the Favorite, so my hunch is that being offline may bypass the problem. 
(a weak answer, but in the lack of alternatives, something to try)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you can delete the related .plist files, **Warning!** this will reset your Finder to factory defaults.

- Open Finder, and click "Go" menu on the very top menu bar.
- Hold down "Option" key and choose Library.
- Navigate to "Preferences" folder, and delete following files (or drag them to Desktop for safety, so you can put them back if needed):

> com.apple.finder.plist
>
> com.apple.sidebarlists.plist

Close all Finder windows and logout your Mac and login again.